# How to get notified of Google Calendar events on a PC

Tags: google-calendar

I need to get some kind of noise or image or pop up notification for events my Windows 10 PC. [But here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) it says:

> Note: To get notifications on your computer, you need to have Google
>   Calendar open in your browser.

I think that's super annoying. Are they referring to have it in a tab?

I can't afford to have Google calendar open in a tab all week only for some dentist appointment in three days. I need to program a pop out notification at a programmed schedule, on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, navigate to the Start Menu, and select the Calendar app in the top-right corner. Once the Calendar is up, to add a Google account you'll need to find the Settings icon, located in the bottom left-hand corner of the app.

More info

http://www.howtogeek.com/224899/how-to-use-your-google-calendar-in-the-windows-10-calendar-app/

Comment: I;m not sure you understood something about my question. It's about an extension or app called "google calendar", you are talking about Windows 10 caendar. I don't think they can be combined, probably were you mistaken? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Santropedro - Did you actually read Raghu's post and the article he linked to? It seems a decent solution to your question. If not, perhaps you can edit/clarify your question.

Comment: @CJM No, I hadn't saw the link sorry! My bad.

Comment: @Santropedro thanks for going through my answer, it worked for me

Comment: @CJM there are always 10 ways to do the same thing will update answer